# Is there a terminal that has something similar to intellisense?

Tags: terminal, console, intellisense

I absolutely love Intellisense when writing code in Visual Studio

Is there a terminal app that has a similar feature that could popup a GUI of suggestions for command or parameter completion based on the context of what i am doing or already typing?